# c# Object Comparison fails

Tags: c#

I have two objects of type `SqlServer.Smo.Column`. If I try to compare one property of both

```
ColumnaOrigen.Properties["DataType"].Value != ColumnaDestino.Properties["DataType"].Value
```

It return `true` even both values are `numeric`.

In the debugger the type showed is `object{string}`; the same happens with other datatypes such as `object{bool}`

1. Why does this happen?
2. How can I compare those values to get the right answer?

Comment: Have you tried to use "Type.Equals"? 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ahwab82%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Usually tests on equality are done using Equals-method. For simple data-types such as `int`, `bool` ... you may also use `==` or `!=`. For strings we use kind of pooling as far as I know that´s why `"1" == "1"` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1- Why this happens ?

Because you are not comparing values of the variables, but their references. Since both variables are `object`, `==` calls [`Object.ReferenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> 2- How can I do to compare those values to get the right answer ?

If both types are `string`, cast them and compare them as strings.

```
string a = ColumnaOrigen.Properties["DataType"].Value as string;
string b = ColumnaDestino.Properties["DataType"].Value as string;

if (!string.Equals(a, b))
{ }
```